# MATLAB CodeCoveragePlugin not accepting subfolder argument

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

many thanks for taking a look.

Currently I have the following script to run my unit tests in matlab:

```
import matlab.unittest.TestSuite
import matlab.unittest.TestRunner
import matlab.unittest.plugins.CodeCoveragePlugin

suite = TestSuite.fromFolder('U:\MATLAB\myFolder\Tests', 'IncludingSubfolders', true);
runner = TestRunner.withTextOutput;
runner.addPlugin(CodeCoveragePlugin.forFolder('U:\MATLAB\myFolder', 'IncludingSubfolders', true));
result = runner.run(suite);
```

The error is currently at the line:

```
runner.addPlugin(CodeCoveragePlugin.forFolder('U:\MATLAB\myFolder', 'IncludingSubfolders', true));
```

Which claims there are too many input arguments. However, the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.codecoverageplugin.forfolder.html#inputarg_tf) clearly states the function can accept three inputs.

Has anyone had experience using this tool and any advice on how to proceed.

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?  The release notes state that the subfolder (and subpackage) functionality on CodeCoveragePlugin were added in R2015b.  FWIW, your code worked fine for me in 15b :)

Comment: 15a, well that's somewhat frustrating! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kim on second thoughts, I believe the functionality was introduced in 2014b no? It mentions it at the bottom of the page http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.codecoverageplugin.forfolder.html

Comment: The method was introduced in 2014b, but the ability to specify subfolders and packages was added in 2015b.  Here is the release note: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#buzej11-28